# Trying to play video Inside a video frame

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to play video Inside a video frame  and that frame should always be at center of main page and another videos should be appeared at the bottom.On clicking bottom videos It will start playing on Above video Frame.Any help on this would be appreciated.

Xaml

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\1280x800 final file.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <RelativePanel x:Name="MainPanel" Grid.Row="0">
            <MediaElement x:Name="load"
                          Source="/Videos/load.mp4"
                          RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>

        </RelativePanel>


    </Grid>
```

Refer Image[image]

Comment: Create a GridView below your Video Frame. Bind the Source of MediaElement to SelectionChanged event of GridView and everytime you tap on an item, Video will play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample as your description.
I set `Grid` as my root panel for the page, and divide it into two rows.I placed `MediaPlayerElement` on the first row and placed `GridView` on the second row.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <MediaPlayerElement
        x:Name="mediaPlayerElement"
        Height="150"
        Margin="0,0,0,10"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
        AutoPlay="True" />
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <GridView
        x:Name="VideoGridView"
        Margin="10,10,0,10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="VideoGridView_ItemClick"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind videoItems}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:VideoItem">
                <Grid
                    Width="100"
                    Height="150"
                    Background="LightGray">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="120" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image
                        Name="VideoProviewImage"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Source="{x:Bind imageSource}"
                        Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="VideoTitle"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Height="30"
                        Text="{x:Bind videoTitle}"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

And then I make a Model for data-binding

```
public class VideoItem
{
    public string imageSource { get; set; }
    public string videoUri { get; set; }
    public string videoTitle { get; set; }

}
public static class VideoManager
{
    public static ObservableCollection<VideoItem> getVideos()
    {
        var videoItems = new ObservableCollection<VideoItem>();
        videoItems.Add(new VideoItem() { imageSource = "/Assets/image.jpg", videoUri = "https://mediaplatstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/windows-universal-samples-media/elephantsdream-clip-h264_sd-aac_eng-aac_spa-aac_eng_commentary-srt_eng-srt_por-srt_swe.mkv", videoTitle = "First" });
        videoItems.Add(new VideoItem() { imageSource = "/Assets/image.jpg", videoUri = "https://mediaplatstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/windows-universal-samples-media/elephantsdream-clip-h264_sd-aac_eng-aac_spa-aac_eng_commentary.mp4", videoTitle = "Second" });
        videoItems.Add(new VideoItem() { imageSource = "/Assets/image.jpg", videoUri = "https://mediaplatstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/windows-universal-samples-media/multivideo-with-captions.mkv", videoTitle = "Third" });
        videoItems.Add(new VideoItem() { imageSource = "/Assets/image.jpg", videoUri = "https://mediaplatstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/windows-universal-samples-media/sintel_trailer-480p.mp4", videoTitle = "Fourth" });
        return videoItems;
    }
}
```

The mediaPlayerElement will play automatically when GridView Item  is clicked.

```
private void VideoGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var vedio = e.ClickedItem as VideoItem;          
    var item = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(vedio.videoUri))); 
    mediaPlayerElement.Source = item;
}
```

[image: Effect]